# ASP.NET 2.2 Core Add user to a model throws nullreference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a Model that has a property Publisher of type ApplicationUser. When I try to create the Model, it gives me a nullreference exception.

In the Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Publisher")]
[ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
public ApplicationUser Publisher { get; set; }
```

In ApplicationUser:

```
public ICollection<Model> PublishedModels { get; set; }
```

The many-to-one relation in the DB context:

```
b.HasMany(u => u.PublishedModels)
     .WithOne(v => v.Publisher)
     .IsRequired()
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

In the Create method of the controller (get the current user):

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

The I get a nullreference on this line:

```
model.Publisher = user;
```

I'm confused, I verified that user is not null. Model is not null and ModelState is valid. Then why can't I assign that value to model.Publisher? The strange thing is that if I don't modify model and just save it to the DB, it works. But I need to add the publisher too. If I only set the date, it's also fine.

This works, but when removing the comments it complains about a nullreference when setting the date.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind(include:"...")] Model model)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.PublicationDate = DateTime.Now;

            //user.PublishedModels.Add(model);

            _context.Add(model);
            //_context.Update(model.Publisher);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /*dex*/)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "...");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

In the following stack trace, it crashes on the first line in the method ...

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
WebApp.Controllers.Admin.ModelController.Create(Model model) in 
ModelController.cs
-
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind(include:"...")] Model model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    user.PublishedModels.Add(model);
    model.PublicationDate = DateTime.Now;
    model.Publisher = user;
    try
    { 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
```

System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: The only thing that could possibly throw this exception on that line is if `model` is null. Either `model` is null, the exception is being thrown from a different place, or you've got something else weird going on like custom getters/setters that are throwing the exception. Post your stack trace.

Comment: No custom getters. It's like I HAVE to save the model to the database in that method, doesn't seem to accept me modifying the posted model. Maybe it has to do with antiforgery?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the full stack trace. It looks like you've modified it. It particular it's not calling out any particular line.

Comment: I modified the name of the model. The thing is that there is no nullreference. When I add the code to get the user, it gets it correctly, I can see the value. Then the next line fails, no matter what line it is. If I remove the user related code, it just works. I do this with an authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

Fail to reproduce your issue, check the difference between your code and below:

1. You defined `PublishedModels` in `ApplicationUser`, but you referenced `PublishedModel`.
2. `DbContext`, for code below, if you did not set the value for `Publisher` or `PublisherId` when creating `Model`, you will get error for you did not set the value for `PublisherId`, but you did not, check whether you keep the model and database same.

   ```
           builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                   .HasMany(u => u.PublishedModels)
                   .WithOne(vv => vv.Publisher)
                   .IsRequired()
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
   ```
3. Method to create model with applicationuser

   ```
           public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Model model)
           {
                   ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                   if (ModelState.IsValid)
                   {
                           model.Publisher = user;
                           _context.Add(model);
                           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                   }
                   return View(model);
           }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it +1. It's a very strange problem, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a nullreference. It's almost as if the behavior is undefined. I scaffolded the controller and views, then added the user property and edited the controller. I could not get it to work. I ended up scaffolding it all again and now it works without making changes to the controller. But I have to bind the foreign key in the form. I'm going to try to edit the newly scaffolded controller and see if I can remove the binding and set it on creation.